# function trigger but somehow does not update the sections

Tags: jquery

I am calling the function as:

```
$("check").on('change',function() {

   function sorting() 
   do the ajax call and after the success:
   $("#check").trigger("change");
}
```

but it somehow does not trigger properly and sometimes, if there are 50 records, after doing ajax action, it shows 75 records or more

what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I would assume there's something wrong with the way you're dealing with the async requests, but without seeing your code it's impossible to tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: It's possible you're making multiple ajax requests and thus multiple sorts that are conflicting with each other.  Javascript is single-threaded, but if you sort also makes ajax calls, it's quite possible they'll be interfering with each other which is why you get more results.

Answer (score 0):

Is your jQuery selector missing the id designation?

```
$("#check").on('change',function() {
```

Comment: If that were the case the code wouldn't work at all. It seems much more likely that the OP has made a typo when composing their question